# Is it possible to develop a multiplayer xbox kinect game?

Tags: kinect, multiplayer, xbox360

I am thinking about developing a game for xbox kinect, but it is a multiplayer game, but there are no multiplayer games for kinect right now, so, i was wondering if it's even possible? Multiplayer as in over the network, not in the same room.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can develop a multiplayer Kinect game for the PC (see [this link](http://kinectforwindows.org/)), but not for XBOX 360, unless you are a Microsoft affiliate, and have access to the [XBOX 360 Native Development](http://www.xbox.com/en-US/developers/xbox360/registereddevelopers) Kit, which requires signing a non-disclosure agreement. This is **NOT** possible using XNA.

Comment: Which leads us to the question: Why not ? From my point of view, the Kinect is just another input device, it should not block the network aspect of any game.