# Error when adding microsoft.kinect to XBOX Project

Tags: kinect, xbox360

iam trying to develop a new  Xbox game using microsoft kinect SDK 1.5 for windows.

when i create a new XBOX360 project and add Microsoft.Kinect as a reference->type using Microsoft.Kinect and Build,  it gives me an error telling:

Warning 1   The primary reference "Microsoft.Kinect" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the framework assembly "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" which could not be resolved in the currently targeted framework. ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client". To resolve this problem, either remove the reference "Microsoft.Kinect" or retarget your application to a framework version which contains "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089".    Xbox360Game1
[image]

and also, with system.dll, system.core.dll

all of these libraries are V2 when adding a new XBox Project.

how can i solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have bad news for you.

**It's not possible develop apps or games for Xbox with the Kinect SDK.** 
It's sad, i know.
The only way to create Xbox games with Kinect is with the XDK (if I'm correct) and it's only for certified professionals.

Comment: Another answer: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8291165/is-it-possible-to-develop-a-multiplayer-xbox-kinect-game?rq=1)

Comment: very thanks for your reply, I am MCP and have an account in App HUB Website, but can not find any download link to get XDK!!